# React to console inputs (commands) - how to handle multiple options most efficient?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

### Some information (don't want to confuse you with a lot of shitty code):

I've done a pretty large console programm (my largest project so far) which helps me a lot with managing some accounts / assets and more. I'm constantly adding more features but at the same time I reshape the code to work on my shitty ***coding style***.

The console program has a lot of ***commands*** the user can type and for every command different methods get called / objects get created / manipulated and so on.

My ***keywords*** which are saved in an `ArrayList<String>` and my ***commands*** have this type: `[keyword] [...n more Strings]`

### DESIGN PROBLEM 1:

I have a method `cmdProcessor(String[] arguments)` which handles the input (command) of the user, and the `[keyword]` is always the first argument `arguments[0]`. That means I have a large number of if-statements of this type: 
`if(arguments[0].equalsIgnoreCase("keyword") callMethod(argmts);` where in the `String[] argmts` the remaining ***arguments[1] ... [n]*** are.

- Is this a good way to handle this or should I go with switch-case?
- Or something else (what?)? Is it better to save the keywords in a `HashMap<String, Method>`?

### DESIGN PROBLEM 2:

The methods (see above `callMethod(argmts)` ), which are triggered by the entered ***keyword*** look even more chaotic. Since the same method can have different numbers and forms of arguments saved in the `String[] argmts` the method is full of `if(argmts.length == ...)` to check length, and every of these if-blocks has a bunch of switch-case options which also have a lot of ifs and so on. The ***last else*** and the ***default-case in switch-case*** I always use for ***error-handling*** (throwing error codes and and explanation why the pattern doesn't match and so on).

- Is this good or are there better ways?
- I thought about using lots of submethods, which would also blow up
  my program and cost a lot of time but maybe improve readability / overview. Is this okay, or what is the best
  option in such cases (lots of ifs and switch-case)?

Since I want to build more and more around this program maybe I should start now to fix bad design before it's too late. :)

Comment: Just use a decent CLI library and get on with writing the real code. For example [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/#_more_complex_syntaxes_commands) supports "command stytax" out of the box. Your homebrew approach sounds, to be honest, like every naive attempt at a CLI parser I have seen. Use someone elses much better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that (JCommander) looks like an easy solution to my problem.

Comment: About problem[1]. I can suggest you to create a UserCmd class and bunch of subclasses. For exsample: 

https://pastebin.com/0uK71dBY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About Design-Problem 1:**

My go-to would be to register a lot of Handlers, which you can base on a common interface and then implement the specific behavior individually. This is good, because the central method handling your input is slim, and you only need to register a lot of singletons once, on initialization. Disadvantage: if you forget one, it will not work. So maybe, you can register them automatically (reflection or something thelike).

Aside from that, a map is better than a List in this case, because (I assume) you don't need a sorting. You need a mapping from key to behavior, so a map seems better (though even a very large set of keywords would probably not be very inefficient, if you stick to a list).

**About Design Problem 2:**

If I was you, I'd use actual Regular-Expression patterns. Take a look at the `java.util.regex.Pattern`-class. You can isolate groups and validate the values you receive. Though it does not spare you the exception/error-handling, it does help a lot in segmentation and interpretation efforts.